# Relationship between eigenvalues of $A-B$ and eigenvalues of $A^2-B^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues

Let us suppose that $A_{n}$ and $B_n$ are sequences of positive definite matrices satisfying

$$c \leq \lambda_{\min}(A_n)\leq \lambda_{\max}(A_n)\leq C$$

and

$$c \leq \lambda_{\min}(B_n)\leq \lambda_{\max}(B_n)\leq C$$

where $\lambda_{\min}$ and $\lambda_{\max}$ are minimal and maximal eigenvalues. Then, what's the relationship between $\|A_n-B_n\|_2$ and $\|A_n^2-B_n^2\|_2$? Is it true that

$$\|A_n-B_n\|_2 \leq \text{constant} \cdot \|A_n^2-B_n^2\|_2$$

where the $2$-norm of a matrix $M$ is the maximum of the absolute value of its minimal eigenvalue and the absolute value of its maximal eigenvalue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The norm you consider is usually called *operator norm*, or the norm *subordinated* to the $\ell^2$ norm over ${\mathbb C}^n$ (or ${\mathbb R}_n$). The correct inequality for positive Hermitian matrices $A$ an $B$ is
$$\|A-B\|_2\le\sqrt{\|A^2-B^2\|_2}.$$
See Exercise 110 of my [additional list](http://www.umpa.ens-lyon.fr/~serre/DPF/exobis.pdf) accompagnying my book *Matrices*, GTM **216** (Springer-Verlag).

Comment: "The norm you consider is usually called ..." or the *spectral norm*, or the norm *induced* by the $\ell^2$ norm, or...

Comment: And of course strictly speaking the OP's definition of that norm is only correct for Hermitian matrices.